# How to parse base64 program data from getParsedAccountInfo?

Tags: getaccountinfo, anchor-program-idl

I've been trying to figure out a way to programmatically derive the descriptive "label" given a program's base58 address, e.g. `cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ` => NFT Candy Machine V2 or `9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin` => Serum DEX V3.

I found a useful answer [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/278/1017) using Anchor to get the following data:

```
"root": {
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "nft_candy_machine", <= this is kind of the data I want
  "instructions": [...],
  "accounts": [...],
  "types": [...],
  "errors": [...]
}
```

But I want to get the full descriptive label `"NFT Candy Machine Program"` that explorer.solana.com displays. I've been trying to use solana web3 `Connection.getParsedAccountInfo` and got so far as getting this result:

```
{
  info: {
    authority: 'AqH29mZfQFgRpfwaPoTMWSKJ5kqauoc1FwVBRksZyQrt',
    data: [
      'f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAMA9wABAAAAwB0.......', <= really long base64 encoded value
      'base64'
    ],
    slot: 114756793
  },
  type: 'programData'
}
```

I tried `const parsedData = Buffer.from( info.data[0], info.data[1] ).toString()` but it's not giving me the right decoded value.

What is the right way to decode this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full descriptive label in the explorer is hardcoded https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/5450f978445cff9ac9959d47a7429e0b78c873e3/explorer/src/utils/tx.ts#L66

So there is no way to programmatically obtain this label, the only way would be to have a more descriptive name field embedded in the IDL.

The way you are converting the base64 program data into a buffer is correct `const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(...info.data)`
However, you cannot really do anything from there because this info.data field is the binary of the program to be run by the solana runtime.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. but do you know how to parse the base64 program data?

Comment: I edited my reply as the decoded is correct but I doubt this is what you are looking for

Comment: awesome that's the answer i was looking for, thanks!